# Efficiency of C string vs C++ strings

Tags: c++, string

The book *[C++ Primer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_B._Lippman)* says

> For most applications, in addition to being safer, it is also more
> efficient to use library strings rather then C-style strings

Safety is understood. Why is the C++ strings library more efficient? After all, underneath it all, aren't strings still represented as character arrays?

To clarify, does the author talk about programmer efficiency (understood) or processing efficiency?

Comment: Less complexity = more productivity = more time to optimize slow code = greater efficiency.

Comment: Are we talking about programmer efficiency or processing efficiency?

Comment: @scientiaesthete Yes, and thus they contribute to the overall energy-minimization of computer programs and a cleaner and more peaceful world ;)

Comment: We could also ask if it's talking about memory efficiency or processor efficiency.

Comment: Also, does everything hold no matter what encoding the strings are in? For example, multibyte encodings such as used in East Asian languages or Unicode's UTF-8?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

C-strings are usually faster, because they do not call malloc/new. But there are cases where `std::string` is faster. Function `strlen()` is O(N), but `std::string::size()` is O(1).

Also when you search for substring, in C strings you need to check for `'\0'` on every cycle, in `std::string` - you don't. In a naive substring search algorithm it doesn't matter much, because instead of checking for `'\0'` you need to check for `i<s.size()`. But modern high-performance substring search algorithms traverse strings in multibyte steps. And the need for a `'\0'` check in every byte slows them down. This is the reason why GLIBC `memmem` is x2 times faster than `strstr`. I did [a lot of benchmarking](http://volnitsky.com/project/str_search) of substring algorithms.

This is true not only for substring search algorithm. Many other string processing algorithms are slower for zero-terminated strings.

Comment: In which way do C strings not need to call `malloc/new`? Whenever you want a dynamically sized string you need dynamically allocated memory, this holds for C strings as well as `std::string`s. And besides that, I think searching for a substring is an algorithm where there shouldn't be a difference between C strings and `std::string`s. And again one of the slightly wrong 50% chosen, but well Ok, it's James's choice which answer to accept.

Comment: @ChristianRau - you need to reread my post. Also did you had a chance to benchmark c-string and std::string substring functions?  I did.

Comment: No, I did no profiling, just the when thinking about searching for a substring I don't neccessarily see the need for computing the length each time, though I might be wrong there. Of yourse I know that the O(1) length is the main advanatage (that's what the other correct answers write, too). But even after rereading, I cannot see how C strings *"do not call malloc/new"*, which is just rubbish and my main critique point in your answer.

Comment: You can put c-string (or almost any other type) into dynamically allocated memory , but you don't have to.  If you dynamically allocate C-string - you will be doing this,  not C-string's  members functions. C-string (as int,double or any POD type) do not call itself malloc/new.

Comment: Well, of course a pointer doesn't allocate itself. But c-strings do not **usually** *"not call malloc/new"*, since using a simple compile time array is not the *usual* way to work with strings, especially in light of any string processing algorithms. Of course you can always throw a `char[1024]` at it and call it a day, but well. But you're right in that in some cases a small char array is ineed appropriate and doesn't require any dynamic allocation, but I would call those cases far from usual, especially when doing elaborate string processing.

Comment: While it is true that with c-strings you need to check for null-terminating character while looping the char array (`while(c != '\0')`), this is not any slower than std::string checking its own boundary condition (`while(i < size)`).

Comment: @Gigi - this might be true only for naive algorithm (but really isn't) which compare a byte at a time.  Modern algorithm use multibyte steps. You can benchmark GLIBC `memmem` and `strstr` - `memmem` will be two times faster.

Comment: @Gigi it is because in most implementations as the std:string object often maintains a size integer field. Of course this is a memory/performance tradeoff, store an extra 32bits or loop through the whole string. O(n) is close enough to O(1) that it can be mostly ignored.

Comment: Ok, this answer gets better and better. I now realize what you meant with your *"check for '\0' every cycle"* statement and it makes sense (but the downvote is tied to the *"usually"* in the first sentence, anyway).

Comment: @Gigi He claims to have benchmarked it, finding `std::string` is faster, and his reason makes sense. `std::string` can operate over many bytes at once with a single instruction. C-style strings must check that a character is not `'\0'` to avoid trying to read memory that the C-string doesn't use or, worse, to avoid reading memory that doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 24):

> Why is C++ strings library more efficient? After all, underneath it all, aren't strings still represented as character arrays?

Because the code which uses `char*` or `char[]` is more likely to be inefficent if not written carefully. For example, have you seen *loop* like this:

```
char *get_data();

char const *s = get_data(); 

for(size_t i = 0 ; i < strlen(s) ; ++i) //Is it efficent loop? No.
{
   //do something
}
```

Is that efficient? No. The time-complexity of `strlen()` is `O(N)`, and furthermore, it is computed in each iteration, in the above code.

Now you may say *"I can make it efficient if I call `strlen()` just once."*. Of course, you can. But you have to do all that sort of optimization *yourself* and *conciously*. If you missed something, you missed CPU cycles. But with `std::string`, many such optimization is done by the class itself. So you can write this:

```
std::string get_data();

std::string const & s = get_data(); //avoid copy if you don't need  it

for(size_t i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; ++i) //Is it efficent loop? Yes.
{
   //do something
}
```

Is that efficient? Yes. The time-complexity of `size()` is `O(1)`. No need to optimize it manually which often makes code look ugly and hard to read. The resulting code with `std::string` is almost always neat and clean in comparison to `char*`.

Also note that `std::string` not only makes your code efficent in terms of CPU cycles, but it also increases programmer efficency!

Comment: The usual way to iterate over a C string is: `for (int i = 0; s[i]; ++i)`, which is efficient. The argument should be about the string class storing the size of the string, making it available in O(1).

Comment: @DanielFleischman: You misread my answer. I gave that example by first asking *"have you seen loop like this?"*, and then added `O(N) vs O(1)`, explaining other pointers in the rest of the answer. (So I dont think the downvote is justified).

Comment: @Nawaz: In gcc's implementation of the C standard library, `strlen` is tagged with an attribute that instructs the compiler that the result of the function call depends only on the arguments (no side effects other than the returned value). This allows the compiler to factor out the `strlen` from the loop. That being said, that is *quality of implementation*, and that optimization is not available on other compiler/library implementations.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas this depends on the quality of the compiler, not something one should rely on for such optimization

Comment: @JimBalter: *"No one does this."* ... You're underestimating the number of programmers who call `strlen(s)` **multiple** times in a *single* function!!!

Comment: @JimBalter: That is *not* what you previously said. You said *"No one does this"* and now you're calling yourself *"honest"*. ;-)

Comment: @JimBalter: and I said *"the code which uses `char*` or `char[]` is **more likely** to be inefficent **if not written carefully**"* . What is wrong in that when you admit it yourself that a billion programmers call `strlen(s)` multiple times in a single function, possibly in loops as well?

Comment: @JimBalter: Goodbye *"No one does this"*. ;-)

Comment: @Jim Balter: In .NET ([C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) and [VB.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)), the *official recommended* way is to call length() in the loop condition. There may or may not be some guarantee that it is efficient. Someone going from C# to C may or may not make the mistake.

Comment: Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663186/initializing-a-two-dimensional-stdvector/59906780#59906780) from C++, using size() in the loop conditions. It may or may not be efficient.

Comment: length() and size() aren't relevant here since they are O(1) and compile to a single fetch whereas strlen() is O(n). This is actually mentioned in the answer, so it's hard to see the point of these comments. Also this conversation is past its expiration date.

Answer (score 9):

A `std::string` knows its length, which makes many operations quicker.

For example, given:

```
const char* c1 = "Hello, world!";
const char* c2 = "Hello, world plus dog!";
std::string s1 = c1;
std::string s2 = c2;
```

`strlen(c1)` is slower than `s1.length()`. For comparisons, `strcmp(c1, c2)` has to compare several characters to determine the strings are not equal, but `s1 == s2` can tell the lengths are not the same and return false immediately.

Other operations also benefit from knowing the length in advance, e.g. `strcat(buf, c1)` has to find the null terminator in `buf` to find where to append data, but `s1 += s2` knows the length of `s1` already and can append the new characters at the right place immediately.

When it comes to memory management, `std::string` allocates additional space every time it grows, which means future append operations don't need to reallocate.

Answer (score 7):

There *are* some cases in which a `std::string` might beat a `char[]`. For example, C-style strings typically don't have an explicit length passed around—instead, the NUL terminator implicitly defines the length.

This means that a loop which continually `strcat`s onto a `char[]` is actually performing O(n²) work, because each `strcat` has to process the entire string in order to determine the insertion point. In contrast, the only work that a `std::string` needs to perform to concatenate onto the end of a string is to copy the new characters (and possibly reallocate storage—but for the comparison to be fair, you have to know the maximum size beforehand and `reserve()` it).

Comment: I'm sure most C developers are wise enough to store the sizes themselves. It'll be about the same speed, but it will also be more error prone and harder to understand due to there being more code - more variables, more function arguments, etc.

Comment: Yep. strlen() was famously used as an example in illustrating the [Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) (it comes in many forms and is very easy to "apply" inadvertently)

Answer (score 3):

Strings are the object which contain character arrays within themselves along with their size and other functionalities. It is better to use strings from a strings library because they save you from allocating and deallocating memory, looking out for memory leaks and other pointer hazards. But as strings are objects, so they take extra space in memory.

[C strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Overview_of_functions) are simply character arrays. They *should* be used when you are working in real time; when you do not know completely about how much memory space you have in hand. If you are using C strings, you would have to take care for memory allocation, then copying data into it via [strcpy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Functions) or character by character, then deallocating after its usage, etc., etc.

So better use strings from a string library if you want to avoid a bunch of headaches.

Strings increase program efficiency but reduce processing efficiency (though not necessarily). Vice versa is with C strings.

Comment: It is not true that `std::string` necessarily reduces processing efficiency.

Comment: That somehow contradicts what the quote in the question says, instead of explaining why the quote says so. It's not about headaches, but about processing efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

Well, an obvious and simple thing how they could be practically more efficient (regarding runtime) is, that they store the string's length along with the data (or at least their `size` method has to be O(1), which says practically the same).

So whenever you would need to find the NUL character in a C string (and thus walk the whole string once) you can just get the size in constant time. And this happens quite a lot, e.g. when copying or concatenating strings and thus allocating a new one beforehand, whose size you need to know.

But I don't know if this is what the author meant or if it makes a huge difference in practice, but it still is a valid point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short point of view.

First of all, C++ strings are objects, so it is more consistent to use them in an object-oriented language.

Then, the standard library comes with a lot of useful functions for strings, iterators, etc. All this stuff is stuff you won't have to code again, so you gain time and you're sure that this code is (almost) bugless.

Finally, C strings are pointers that are kind of difficult to understand when you're new, and they bring complexity. Since references are preferred over pointers in C++, it makes more sense to use *std::string* instead of C strings.

Comment: C++ is not an object oriented language.

Comment: @JonathanWakely It is not *only* an object-oriented language. However, it is definitely possible to perform object-oriented programming in it, which in my opinion is the only reasonable definition of "object-oriented language."

Comment: Object oriented programming IS the basic difference in C and C++. Originally C++ was named 'C with classes'.

Comment: @CodingMash, there are many other differences, such as templates, which have nothing to do with OO. C++ is a multi-paradigm language, not an OO language. You can write OO code in C (with enough effort) but that doesn't make it an "OO language"

Comment: I just said the basic difference. you are right there are many others as templates, namespaces, etc, etc. I was merely commenting on that 'c++ is not and object oriented language'. It may not be PURELY oop language, its has the procedural paradigm as well (no offence meant)

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with C-style strings is that one really can't do much with them unless one knows about the data structures in which they are contained.  For example, when using "strcpy", one must know that the destination buffer is writable, and has enough space to accommodate everything up to the first zero byte in the source (of course, in all too many cases, one doesn't really know that for certain...).  Very few library routines provide any support for allocating space on demand, and I think all those that do work by allocating it unconditionally (so if one had a buffer with space for 1000 bytes, and one wants to copy a 900-byte string, code using those methods would have to abandon the 1000-byte buffer and then create a new 900-byte buffer, even though it might be better to simply reuse the 1000-byte buffer).

Working with an object-oriented string type would in many cases not be as efficient as working with standard C-strings but figuring out the optimal ways to allocate and reuse things.  On the other hand, code which is written to optimally allocate and reuse strings may be very brittle, and slight changes to requirements could require making lots of tricky little tweaks to the code--failing to tweak the code perfectly would likely result in bugs which may be obvious and severe, or subtle but even more severe.  The most practical way to avoid brittleness in code which uses standard C strings is to design it very conservatively.  Document maximum input-data sizes, truncate anything which is too big, and use big buffers for everything.  Workable, but not terribly efficient.

By contrast, if one uses the object-oriented string types, the allocation patterns they use will likely not be optimal, but will likely be better than the 'allocate everything big' approach.  They thus combine much of the run-time efficiency of the hand-optimized-code approach with safety that's better than the 'allocate everything big' approach.