# Initializing a two-dimensional std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, stdvector

So, I have the following:

```
std::vector< std::vector <int> > fog;
```

and I am initializing it very naively like:

```
for(int i=0; i<A_NUMBER; i++)
{
    std::vector <int> fogRow;
    for(int j=0; j<OTHER_NUMBER; j++)
    {
         fogRow.push_back(0);
    }
    fog.push_back(fogRow);
}
```

And it feels very wrong... Is there another way of initializing a vector like this?

Comment: I would recommend a 1d vector implementation for a 2d vector if you don't require more space than `std::vector<int>::max_size()`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13937325/942596)

Comment: It would have been nice if at least one of the answers didn't involve **copying** the inner vector: memset is faster than memcpy (and calloc even better if operator new gets inlined).

Answer (score 356, accepted):

Use the [`std::vector::vector(count, value)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) constructor that accepts an initial size and a default value:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > fog(
    ROW_COUNT,
    std::vector<int>(COLUMN_COUNT)); // Defaults to zero initial value
```

If a value other than zero, say `4` for example, was required to be the default then:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > fog(
    ROW_COUNT,
    std::vector<int>(COLUMN_COUNT, 4));
```

I should also mention uniform initialization was introduced in C++11, which permits the initialization of `vector`, and other containers, using `{}`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > fog { { 1, 1, 1 },
                                    { 2, 2, 2 } };
```

Comment: What if I make the storage class of the `std :: vector <std :: vector <int>>` as `static` ?

Comment: reference for Error: "Expected parameter declarator": 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68247443/2918210

Comment: In this way, it seems that first a template vector is created and then it's copied ROW_COUNT times. So there will be ROW_COUNT + 1 vector<int> created, is it right?

Answer (score 155):

Let's say you want to initialize a two-dimensional vector, m*n, with the initial value to be 0. We could do this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int m = 2, n = 5;

    vector<vector<int>> vec(m, vector<int> (n, 0));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just earned a 'Good Answer' because of this answer. Other people already gave the same answer, but those who upvote this one may be similar to me when I came to this post, that we didn't recognize that some other answers are actually the same answer. I think it might be because three reasons: 1) this code could be copied, pasted, and run right away 2) `std::` makes it longer and people might like short and direct answer; 3) the long naming of variable confuses beginners. I'm a beginner too, don't really know how important we need `std::`, need a code runnable so I know what each variable does

Answer (score 37):

There is no `append` method in `std::vector`, but if you want to make a vector containing `A_NUMBER` vectors of `int`, each of those containing `other_number` zeros, then you can do this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> fog(A_NUMBER, std::vector<int>(OTHER_NUMBER));
```

Answer (score 11):

The general syntax, as depicted already is:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > v (A_NUMBER, std::vector <int> (OTHER_NUMBER, DEFAULT_VALUE))
```

Here, the vector 'v' can be visualised as a two dimensional array, with 'A_NUMBER' of rows, with 'OTHER_NUMBER' of columns with their initial value set to 'DEFAULT_VALUE'.

Also it can be written like this:

```
std::vector <int> line(OTHER_NUMBER, DEFAULT_VALUE)
std::vector<std::vector<int> > v(A_NUMBER, line)
```

Inputting values in a 2-D vector is similar to inputting values in a 2-D array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < A_NUMBER; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < OTHER_NUMBER; j++) {
         std::cin >> v[i][j]
     }
}
```

Examples have already been stated in other answers....!

Answer (score 8):

I think the easiest way to make it done is:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>v(10, std::vector<int>(11, 100));
```

10 is the size of the outer or global vector, which is the main one, and 11 is the size of inner vector of type int, and initial values are initialized to 100!

Answer (score 8):

The recommended approach is to use a fill constructor to initialize a two-dimensional vector with a given default value:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> fog(M, std::vector<int>(N, default_value));
```

where, M and N are dimensions for your two-dimensional vector.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what worked for me:

```
vector<vector<int>> minA{ROW_SIZE, vector<int>(COLUMN_SIZE, VALUE)};
```

Comment: interesting, I thought we should enclose `ROW_SIZE, vector<int>(COLUMN_SIZE, VALUE)` with parentheses, instead of curly braces (I know that yours works too).

Answer (score 4):

This answer will help to easily initialize 2d vector after declaration.

```
int n=4,m=3;
int default_value = 0;

std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;

matrix.resize(m, std::vector<int>(n, default_value));
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to initialize a two-dimensional integer vector with n rows and m column, each having value '**VAL**'.

Write it as

```
std::vector<vector<int>> arr(n, vector<int>(m, VAL));
```

This VAL can be an integer type variable or constant, such as 100.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet copies one two-dimensional vector to another. And gives us a clear picture of how to initialize the 2D vector.

```cpp
void copyVectorToVector(vector<vector<int>> matrix) {

        int rowNumber = matrix.size();
        int columnNumber = matrix[0].size();
        vector<vector<int>> result(rowNumber, vector<int> (columnNumber, 0));

        for(int i=0;i<matrix.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<matrix[i].size();j++){
                result[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
                cout<<result[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

multiplication table with 2D vector
the first 10 is for ROW, second 10 for COLUMN

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> multiplication (10,std::vector<int>(10));
for(int i{0}; i<multiplication.size(); ++i){
    for(int j{0}; j<multiplication[i].size(); ++j){
        multiplication[i][j] = j * i;
    }
}

for(int i{1}; i < multiplication.size(); ++i){
    for(int j{1}; j < multiplication[i].size(); ++j){
        std::cout<<multiplication[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Additionally, if someone wants to initialize only the first col values to some different value(say 2) from the rest of the default values(say 1).

```
int rows = 3, cols = 4;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(rows, std::vector<int>(cols, 1));  
for (int r = 0 ; r < rows ; r++) matrix[r][0] = 2;
```

```
2 1 1 1
2 1 1 1
2 1 1 1
```

Answer (score -3):

My C++ STL code to initialise a 5*3 two-dimensional vector with zero:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // If we want to initialise a two-dimensional vector with 0;
    vector<vector<int>> v1(5, vector<int>(3, 0));

    for(int i=0; i<v1.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<v1[i].size(); j++)

            cout << v1[i][j] << " ";

            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code as posted will not compile; it is incomplete.

Comment: The code ought to be explained. At first glance, it looks like it doesn't do anything due to the dominating nested `for` loops and other ceremony, but the magic is presumably in  `vector<vector<int>> v1(5, vector<int>(3, 0));`?