# Vector declaration "expected parameter declarator"

Tags: c++, vector

I have a line of code inside a class's private member variables:

```
vector<double> dQdt(3)
```

When compiling in xcode, this gives an error "expected parameter declarator." I think I provided sufficient info. I don't see anything wrong with this declaration.

Answer (score 29):

You have to initialize the variable in the constructor's initializer list:

```
class X 
{
    private:
     vector<double> dQdt;
    public:
     X() : dQdt(3) {}
};
```

Answer (score 27):

If you read e.g. [this member initialization reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) you will learn that default member initialization have to be a brace or equals initializer. I.e. you need to either use curly-braces:

```
std::vector<double> dQdt{ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
```

or using the equals character:

```
std::vector<double> dQdt = std::vector<double>(3);
```

Since this was introduced with the C++11 standard, you need to enable that in your environment.

Comment: But those aren't the same thing. The first creates a single element with value 3. The second creates 3 elements with default initialization (0.0 in this case).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, if you take [@Raman's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39560305/4561887) and combine it with your answer, you get the best answer! Then, it would clearly cover all 3 valid techniques: 1) use an initializer list in the class or struct constructor, as @Raman shows, OR 2) use the brace initializer `type var{some_default_val};` at the site of the variable declaration (like you show), OR 3) use the equals character `type var = some_default-val;` (like you also show).

Answer (score 12):

I got this error while trying to compile my C++ code having an initialized vector.
**Change the () to {} worked for me in the initialization part;**
Earlier my code looked like this:

```
vector<vector<int>> minA(11, vector<int>(11, INT_MAX));
```

I changed my code to replace circular brackets with curly braces and the error disappered.

```
vector<vector<int>> minA{11, vector<int>(11, INT_MAX)};
```

Comment: This worked for me. Any place where I can read up more on this?

Comment: @abhinav1602 but do you know why?

Answer (score 8):

The parameter for constructors of data members should be written in the initializer list of your class' constructor. That is, instead of

```
class Foo {
    vector<double> dQdt(3);
};
```

You should write

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : dQdt(3) {}
private:
    vector<double> dQdt;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

As well as initializing in the initializer list of the constructor, you can initialize with a brace initializer list:

```
class Foo {
    vector<double> dQdt{3};
};
```

The actual text of the error is because the compiler was expecting you to declare a function, taking an argument of some type, and return the `vector<double>`.  `3` is not a valid declaration of a parameter to a function.

Comment: This will create a vector with a single element `3`. Unlike OP's code, which would create 3 zeros if it worked.

Comment: Thus far, the only answer that explains WHY the original syntax fails.

Answer (score -1):

The question is already answered the following however works as well.
**(** Which might be more useful to assign initial values. For example 24 times the 42. **)**

```
const int default_value = 42;

struct foo
{
    vector<double> hour{vector<double>(24,default_value)};
};
```