# Initialilze an array of vectors with zeros in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I want a array of vectors with 0 as a single element in all the individual vectors. Is there a much more efficient way? does this work?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){

        int lastAnswer = 0;
        int n,q;
        cin >> n >> q;
        vector<int> seqArr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                fill(seqArr[i].begin(),seqArr[i].end(),0);
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: care to explain?

Comment: Indeed, since the vector’s size is 0. You can use seqArr[i].push_back(0); instead.

Comment: `vector<int> seqArr[n];` require Variable-Length-Array (VLA) which is a C11 feature not available in C++

Comment: Why don't you try `vector<vector<int> >`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing a two dimensional std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663186/initializing-a-two-dimensional-stdvector)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a vector if you want an array with a variable length:

```
vector<vector<int>> seqArr(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    seqArr[i].push_back(0);
}
```

or simply

```
vector<vector<int>> seqArr(n, vector<int>(1, 0));   // n vectors with one element 0
```

[Variable-Length-Array (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) is a C99 feature that is not available in C++. In C++, the size of an array must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

As variable length arrays are not a part of c++, I'd recommend using a vector of vectors, which also solved your initialization problem:

```
 vector<vector<int>> sequArray(n,{0}); //vector of n vectors, each containing a single 0
```