# Populate a 3D vector with class objects

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a class object called Cube:

```
class Cube{
  public:    
    Cube();
};

Cube::Cube(){}
```

I create a 3D grid of the Cube objects as such:

```
 vector<vector<vector<Cube>>> grid;
```

Now I want to populate it with a certain amount of Cube objects. Essentially I want to do the same thing as if I was creating a 3D array:

```
Cube grid[10][10][10]
```

Is this possible in C++?

Comment: You can do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663186/initializing-a-two-dimensional-stdvector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're calling the `std::vector` default constructor, however there's also a constructor that takes a size and item value. For the full list, see [the cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

So you can actually do this:

```
vector<vector<vector<Cube>>> grid(10, vector<vector<Cube>>(10, vector<Cube>(10, Cube());
```

Which will give you a 10x10x10 3D vector filled with `Cube()` (default Cube) objects.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much.