# C++: pass matrix of pointers by const reference

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, reference, constants

My question is kinda simple and probably silly, but if I have a dynamic matrix like `int ** max` and I pass it to a function `calculateCost(int ** max, int n))`.

My question is: how can I pass it as `const` reference?

Comment: Do you mean something like `int ** const& max`? Why?

Comment: Why do you want to pass a pointer as a const reference in the first place? It has no benefits whatsoever.

Comment: Do you mean in such a way, that the elements can't be changed?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a pass a pointer reference [(see this answer)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

> Because references are not objects, there are no arrays of references,
>   no pointers to references, and no references to references:
>
> ```
> int& a[3]; // error
> int&* p;   // error
> int& &r;   // error
> ```

You may wanna use the STL's [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to replace every pointer you have.
    int calculateCost(const std::vector> &max, int n);

This will allow you to do all the basic operators a pointer can do, but with extra stuffs like easier [init](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), resize, and [ranged_for_loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

```
template<typename T>
using matrix_t = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

size_t width = 5, height = 3;
// std::vector<std::vector<int>> is the same as matrix_t<int>
matrix_t<int> my_matrix(height, std::vector<width, 0>);
```

Here are some useful links to replace malloc, new, delete...
- [2d vector from 2d const array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17663236/12642121stdvector)
- [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)
- [shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)
- [make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)
- [make_shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)

Have a happy new year !

EDIT:
As said in the above comments, there is no use to use refs in your case, you can just use const double pointers

Comment: A reference to a pointer is fine. You're saying a pointer to a reference isn't possible, but that's not the same thing at all.

Comment: Thanks, should i edit it to "You cannot pass a pointer reference" ?
Also i don't understand "A reference to a pointer is fine."

Comment: What I wished was something like const int ** &m because, correct me if I am wrong, the m of the method is a copy (I have copy constructor)

Comment: Pointers avoid copy construction, you can just do `const int **m`