# How does C++ create different vectors in two dimensional vector initialization?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, std

I saw several places ([e.g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663186/initializing-a-two-dimensional-stdvector)) where 2-dim vector can be initialized like this

```
vector<vector<int> > vec(3, vector<int>(2, 0));
```

What I am thinking is that this code is evaluated to following

```
auto tmp = vector<int>(2, 0);
vector<vector<int> > vec(3, tmp);
```

If I am correct, then 3 elements of `vec` all refer to a same reference.
Which means that modifying `vec[0][1]` also modifies `vec[1][1]`.

If I am wrong, how does C++ make the initialization of each element in `vec` be a different reference?

Comment: Arguments get copied so they won't refer to the same object.

Comment: If they all were to refer to the same object, then modifying any one of the three elements would result in the whole object being changed altogether.

Comment: You're obviously used to another language where reference semantics is the default.   In C++ value semantics is the default, so the default is that `tmp` will be copied three times (three distinct instances created, which are all a copy of `tmp`) not referred to three times.   (It is possible to explicitly force reference semantics, but that isn't done with `std::vector`)

Comment: @Peter this means that even with my pseudo code (the latter code with `tmp`), all 3 elems of `vec` also refer to different vectors

Comment: @transang Yes, all three elements are different instances but having same value set of tmp.

Comment: Note: `vector`s of `vector`s can be surprisingly slow because the memory used could be scattered, making it harder for the CPU to take full advantage of the cache. Consider using [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301) instead.

Comment: @user4581301 do you have any example to show that memory used by vector is scattered. So far, I have been using a for loop for iterate over any vector with the assumption that their elements have consecutive memory addresses

Comment: Each `vector` contains a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, so a `vector` is contiguous. A `vector` of `vector`s requires multiple `vectors`, each with their own pointer to their own dynamically allocated array. The outer `vector` contains a pointer to an array of the inner `vector`, and each of the inner `vector`s contains a pointer do a different array containing its row or column of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) reference

> 3) Constructs the container with count copies of elements with value value.

There are no references to `tmp`, just copies. All the individual vectors are distinct, and modifying one won't modify any of the others.

Answer (score 2):

By default, almost all C++ containers (including [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) take their arguments by copy, so:

```cpp
auto tmp = vector<int>(2, 0);
vector<vector<int> > vec(3, tmp);
```

Now, the vector creates three copies of 'tmp' completely unrelated to each other and stores it inside itself.

---

Note that however, what you are *trying to do is possible*, by using a [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), like so: `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int>>>`.

*Example:*

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto tmp = std::vector<int>(2, 0);
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int>>> a(3, std::ref(tmp));
    a[0].get()[0] = 2;
    a[1].get()[1] = 10;
    a[2].get()[0] = 30;
    std::cout << "'tmp' contains: ";
    for (auto const& elem : tmp)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
}
```

> Output:
>   'tmp' contains: 30 10