# Garbage value with getline

Tags: c++, getline, garbage

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char c[50];

    //cin>>c;
    cin.getline(c,50);

    //cout.write(c,50);
    cout<<c;
    getch();
}
```

I get garbage value if i input anything less than 50 characters. Why is it so ?

Comment: Initialize your array: `c[50]`

Comment: And, __please__ use standard C++, code too. No `void main`, and don't forget to include the appropriate members from `namespace std;`.

Comment: You should prefer using `std::string s; std::getline(std::cin, s);` instead.

Comment: iostream.h is not a standard header (neither is conio.h, but that's a bit different).

Answer (score 1):

**You didn't initialize your array:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    clrscr();

    char c[50] = {};//initialize your array here!

    cin.getline(c,50);
    cout<<c;

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Also:

- [iostream.h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/214242/866930) is outdated.
- If you're aiming for cross-platform development avoid: `<conio.h>` and consequently, the [functions it defines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) used in your code: `clscr()` and `getch()`.
- Avoid C-Strings where possible, if you can. You're using C++, use: the `<string>` library and `std::string`. Read more about that here: [Efficiency of C-String vs C++Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124263/efficiency-of-c-string-vs-cstrings)
- A similar argument can be made for buffered input, using `cin.getline()`, but I don't know your ultimate goal, so I can't comment adequately on that. But, it does seem like you're trying to do a buffered input.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and clean approach

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    getline(std::cin, str);
    cout<<str;
    std::cin.get();    //or std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Some points to be noted:

1. The new standard specifies that main() should have a return type of `int` and not `void`.(not returning anything defaults to `int` return)
2. Even `getchar()` is obsolete.
3. use `std::string` insteead `char` arrays as it is easy and safe to implement

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem using the specified answers, because I didn't realize my file was encoded in 16 bits. So I had to use std::wstring (and std::wifstream).